# How to start the loop again if the length of the input is not 1 (so it is not a 4 digit number)?

Tags: python-2.7

```
import random 
guesses = 0
ons = 0
ins = 0
while True: **#while loop which I want to restart if any of the user inputs are longer than 1 digit**
    number = random.sample(range(0,9),4) #random 4 digit number
```

> Creates random unique number

```
    print(number) 
    number1 = raw_input("Please enter your first digit or exit")
    if len(str(number1)) !=  1:
        print("number is not 4 digits")
        break
        True
```

> If the length of the user input is not 1 then it can't be 4 digits so at this point I want it to restart the loop after printing that up.

```
    elif number1 == "exit":
        print(number)
        False
        exit() 
    number2 = raw_input("Please enter your second digit")
    if len(str(number2)) !=  1:
        print("number is not 4 digits")
        break
        True
    number3 = raw_input("Please enter your third digit")
    if len(str(number3)) !=  1:
        print("number is not 4 digits")
        break
        True
```

> If the length of the user input is not 1 then it cant be 4 digits so at this point I want it to restart the loop after printing that up.

```
    number4 = raw_input("Please enter your fourth digit")
    if len(str(number4)) !=  1:
        print("number is not 4 digits")
        break
        True
```

Comment: what's the relationship between a 1-character text and 4 digit numbers!?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you want to use a ***continue*** instead of ***break***.

*Break* takes you out of the loop.

*Continue* does not break the loop, it takes the control to next iteration.

A quick search for python shows this: [break and continue in loops](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops)